# Is there any way to send a friend request with discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord.py

I want to add a discord bot to a group chat, and the only way I know how is to add them as a friend first. How do I make a bot send a friend request? I'm pretty sure its possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO Nick, please make sure you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Hmm, the title isn't very good is it?

Comment: There, is that better?

Comment: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#bot-vs-user-accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Bots cannot have friends**

https://discordapp.com/developers/#bot-vs-user-accounts

> Bot accounts have a few differences in comparison to normal user
> accounts, namely:
>
> Bots are added to guilds through the OAuth2 API, and cannot accept
> normal invites.
>
> **Bots cannot have friends, nor be added to or join Group DMs**.
>
> Bots do not have a maximum number of Guilds (unlike user accounts,
> which are limited to 100).
>
> Bots have an entirely separate set of [Rate Limits](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#rate-limits).