# How to make HTTP Request with node.js using Discord Rest Api

Tags: node.js, discord

Hi i want to make a friend request with node.js, i tried something but doesn't work

```js
 const https = require('https')

 const options = {
            hostname: `https://discord.com/api/v6/users/@me/relationships/${member.id}`,
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              'Authorization': `Bot ${token}`
            }
          }

          const req = https.request(options, res => {
            console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
          
            res.on('data', d => {
              process.stdout.write(d)
            })
          })
          
          req.on('error', error => {
            console.error(error)
          })
```

But i got that error, i hope you can help me

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_FAIL https://discord.com/api/v6/users/@me/relationships/734500771730554942    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26) {
  errno: -3004,
  code: 'EAI_FAIL',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'https://discord.com/api/v6/users/@me/relationships/734500771730554942'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at the [Official API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user) for the `users` resource you are using. `/relationships/` doesn't even seem to be a supported URI. It's likely the `/users/@me/relationships` endpoint is part of the client only and not exposed to bots i.e. the official Discord API.

This is sort of similar to: [Is there any way to send a friend request with discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355348/is-there-any-way-to-send-a-friend-request-with-discord-py).